# heightForHeaderInSection only called once

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, header, swift3

Coding in Swift 3.  Have a tableView with custom cells and header.

I have a tableView with custom cells and headers.  The headers have two (2) labels in them and have dynamic cell heights since the labels may be long.  My problem is the first time the tableView and sections are configured the label appears as it should, HOWEVER, after scrolling down and then back up the headers' layout somehow breaks.

[image: When tableView first loads and user scrolls down everything appears fine]

As you can see below, after I scroll down then back up to the cells, the label is getting cutoff.

[image: After scrolling down and back up label is cut off]

After printing out what methods are being called I found that the first time scrolling down the tableView the following two (2) override functions are called.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    print("\(section) heightForHeaderInSection")
    print("\(section) returning AUTO for header")
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    print("\(section) viewForHeaderInSection")
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionHeader") as! QuestionHeader
    header.delegate = self
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    header.questionTextLabel.text = String(questionStringArray[section])
    header.questionNumberLabel.text = (String(section + 1) + ")")
    return header.contentView
}
```

But when i scroll back up ONLY the viewForHeader function is called and I think because the height is no longer being set to UITableViewAutomaticDimension the labels get cutoff?

Any ideas?

Comment: @ozgur I tried upvoting but accidentally 'undone' it and it wont let me.  Would you post your answer so I can upvote you?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `header` instead of `header.contentView` from `tableView: viewForHeaderInSection:` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...
  ...
  return header
}
```